# Adding @RunWith(PowerMockrunner.class) to test gives all other tests NPE

Tags: android, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I have a testclass where I am running Mockito tests, like:

```
public class ViewModelTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void openQuestion() {
        viewModel.openQuestion(context, QUESTION_ID);
        verify(questionRouter).open(context, QUESTION_ID);    //just an example
    }

}
```

Everything is working as should. However, I have to mock a static method in one of my test classes, so I add PowerMock to my class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Uri.class)
public class ViewModelTest { ...
```

and dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2'
```

But when I now try to run the tests (let's say I have 15 test methods) I get  NPE on most test methods:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.Viewmodel.prepare(StartViewModel.java:126)
```

I get NPE even in the method where I try to mock the static method:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Uri.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Uri.parse(anyString())).thenReturn(otherUri);
```

Before you downvote&vote to close for NPE, I have really looked at most answers in SO and other sites, tried many of them which of none worked for me. I followed tutorials for Powermock but I still get this errors, and I do not understand why. This is my last resort to try to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the test with the right way, just replace

```
PowerMockito.when(Uri.parse(anyString())).thenReturn(otherUri);
```

with when of Mockito

```
 Mockito.when(Uri.parse(anyString())).thenReturn(otherUri);
```

and add this file `https://gist.github.com/badr-ghazouan/1edbed170ce968ef0011f2721911ffc6` to the resource folder under test folder, mockito will load it automatically without doing anything.

Hope this works for you